# How to implement a page loader animation only for webpages that take more than a certain amount of time to load?

Tags: javascript, html, css, pageload

I've got a page loader animation currently working successfully by calling window.onload() in my JavaScript, but I'd like to tweak the code so that the loader animation only triggers if the webpage takes more than a certain amount of time to load. I'm attempting to avoid having the animation display every time that the user navigates to a new page, and only when it's necessary.

Below is my current HTML, CSS, and JS code, if it's helpful.

HTML:

```
<div class="loader">
        <img class="loading-gif" src="./assets/img/loading.gif" alt="Page Loading...">
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.loader {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1001;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: var(--bg-color);
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.loading-gif {
    width: 100px;
}

.loader.fade-out {
    animation: fadeOut var(--speed);
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes fadeOut {
    100% {
        opacity: 0;
        visibility: hidden;
    }
}
```

JavaScript:

```
window.onload = function() {
    const loader = document.querySelector(".loader")
    loader.classList.add("fade-out")
}
```

Thank you so much for any help that you can provide!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a word, this isn't possible. To achieve this effect you would need to know in advance the rate at which the client will download your webpage and the assets required for the webpage's initial render. You can't know, or even reliably predict, the client's download rate over time because the variables that affect network conditions are too complex. For example, the end user may enter a tunnel while downloading your webpage causing a sudden and unpredictable decrease in available download bandwidth, or other applications on the end user's device may make network requests that compete with the download in progress for bandwidth.

The best you can do to approximate this effect would be to use the `onprogress` event of `XMLHttpRequest` to determine the current download rate and the size of the asset being transferred to calculate when the asset will finish downloading, ASSUMING the download rate remains the same.

Here's a snippet you could use to figure out how to approximate the effect.

```
const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', '/myasset.json}', true);

xhr.onprogress = e => {
    if (e.lengthComputable) {
        const percentComplete = (e.loaded / e.total) * 100;
        console.log(percentComplete, 'percentComplete');
    }
}

xhr.onload = function() {
        console.log("loaded");
}

xhr.send();
```

Comment: Thanks so much, Neil! Your explanation makes perfect sense. I've decided to simply shorten the duration of my page-loading fadeOut animation, so that when pages load very quickly, the effect is barely noticeable. I very much appreciate you taking the time to reply and share your insights on this!

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, but I'm not 100% sure. Basically turn all html into text and inject it into a root div; if the slowest content isn't found, conditionally load page loader, and check again until found to fade loader.

```js
 window.onload = function() {
   
          let yourContent = `<div>
              Your site's content:
              <div>Content A</div>
              <div>Content B</div>
              <div id="check">Content C</div>
            </div>`
          
          let loader = `<div class="loader">
              <img class="loading-gif" src="./assets/img/loading.gif" alt="Page Loading...">
          </div>`;
          
          let wrap = document.getElementById("loader-wrap");
  
          let root = document.getElementById("root"); 
   
          //switch these for loader render
          root.innerHTML = yourContent;
          // setTimeout(()=>root.innerHTML = yourContent,1000);
   
          let interval = setInterval( ()=> {
             console.log("checking...")
             
             if(root.children[0]){
               let check = document.getElementById("check")
               if(check.textContent === "Content C"){
                 const loader = document.querySelector(".loader");
                 if(loader) loader.classList.add("fade-out");
                 //don't forget to clear it
                 clearInterval(interval);
                 console.log("done")
               }

             } else {
               if(!wrap.children[0]) wrap.innerHTML = loader;
             }
          },100)
                
    }
```

```css
    .loader {
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        z-index: 1001;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        background: var(--bg-color);
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
    }

    .loading-gif {
        width: 100px;
    }

    .fade-out {
        animation: fadeOut 1s;
        animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    }

    @keyframes fadeOut {
        100% {
            opacity: 0;
            visibility: hidden;
        }
    }
```

```html
 <div id="root">
      
 </div>
 <div id="loader-wrap">

</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, Pavlos, for providing that reply! Unless I'm misunderstanding, by including the setTimeout() check inside the window.onload function, aren't we simply adding the amount of time set by SetTimeout() before my GIF animation fades out? In other words, won't all DOM elements (including the one with the id of "check") have already loaded in order to trigger window.onload?

Comment: You're assessment is correct; I was focused on a slow element rather than the entire page. I gave it one more shot (see my answer).

Comment: Thanks very much, Pavlos. I'll play around with the approach that you're recommending and see if I can get the desired result. I appreciate your thoughts on the matter.